# Как Рандомно генерировать фотографии?

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте Как Рандомно генерировать фотографии? через html javascript что бы нажать на кнопку оно генерировала фотографии из папки

Comment: Можете обьяснить что вы хотите видеть? примером

Comment: Например нажав на кнопку button появился 1 фото нажав еще раз фото поменялось рандомно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рандомно выбирает, но может быть несколько раз выберит одну фотку

```js
var images = [
             "https://s27.postimg.org/a6iaie0tb/image.png",
             "https://s27.postimg.org/euyadkpzz/image.png",
             "https://s27.postimg.org/i37d4d1nj/image.png",
             "https://s27.postimg.org/99ggn9eov/image.png",
             "https://s27.postimg.org/lww7zrtlr/image.png" ];

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#bt").on("click", function(){
 var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
 $("#show").attr("src",images[rand]);
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><img id="show" src="https://s27.postimg.org/a6iaie0tb/image.png"></div>
<button id="bt">Change images</button>
```